# How to analyse user form input on a website automatically

Tags: javascript, python, forms, backend

I'm in the process of designing a website which will take user information and a file from a user on a website. My aim is to then take this information, run a script on it and then return the user a document with the analysed information on it by email (which they have provided). The script is written in Python but theoretically could be written in most languages. I'm a bit stuck on where to begin so I'm looking for suggestions on how to do this in terms of how to structure this project and make it as automatic as possible. I know Python and have recently learned react but my backend knowledge is poor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to start by actually knowing how data analysis works and how to code it, you can start with this simple [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-analysis-with-python/) that shows how you make:

- histograms.
- bar charts.
- Boxplot.

It shows a few ways of handling data, etc in python!.

In terms of "structure", I would say it depends on what type of Data you are working with, if the user is doing a form or quiz then you can save the answers to variables which you then process before sending it back.

If else your platform has a selection of categories then you can try saving what your user upvotes/likes. You could also learn how to work with databases, start with these [excercises](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_database.asp) that can give you more inspiration and solutions.

Really hopes this sets you on the right path, good luck deving!